# Logo appears for only a second and then disappears

Tags: c, libvlc

I am trying to display a logo on top of a video played with libvlc (2.0.2). I tried to find some documentation, but I had no luck. Here is the best attempt I could come up with:

```
libvlc_video_set_logo_string(m_player->core(), 1, "logo_1365886316.png");  //logo file path (I've also tried logo_1365886316.png,0,5000)
libvlc_video_set_logo_int(m_player->core(), libvlc_logo_x, 500);  //x-coordinate
libvlc_video_set_logo_int(m_player->core(), libvlc_logo_y, 100); //y-coordinate
libvlc_video_set_logo_int(m_player->core(), libvlc_logo_opacity, 255);

// I've tried with the following, but I had no luck.
//libvlc_video_set_logo_int(m_player->core(), libvlc_logo_repeat, -1);
//libvlc_video_set_logo_int(m_player->core(), libvlc_logo_delay, 6000); 

libvlc_video_set_logo_int(m_player->core(), libvlc_logo_enable, 1);
```

What is happening is that my logo is visible for few milliseconds or so, and then it disappears. If I try to initialize logo again, nothing is showing up. Also, if this is important, I am initializing logo after video has been started.

I don't know why this is happening. As per various forum posts, I am doing everything ok, and I am not initializing anything on the stack so it can be freed after I exit init function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official VideoLAN forum seems to provide the answer you needed: the logo feature is probably broken in VLC 2.0.X ([source](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=105316)).

Also, [another thread](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=82309) on the same forum seems to confirm that you are doing the right thing when you wait for the video to be playing to display the logo (at least, you know it does not come from you).

I think you simply should consider the feature broken for now and hope someone will provide a patch someday. Unless you feel like writing this patch by yourself.

**EDIT:** And by the way, I checked the [vlc-devel mailing list](http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/) from the date of the forum message (october 2012) to today, and did not find anything about a possible patch. The only thing that I found about the logo functions was [a message](http://mailman.videolan.org/pipermail/vlc-devel/2012-October/090481.html) stating that some other logo-related feature appears not to work since 2.0.3 (which was also the version cited in the forum post I shared in this message).

Answer (score 3):

It's not broken! It's working for me. You have to add the option `--sub-filter=logo` to your options array that you pass to `libvlc_new()`.

Comment: Thanks! I am not currently at home, but I will try next week!